# Uso correto de lambda com filter()

Tags: python, python-3.x, expressões-lambda, dicionário, filter

Segue um exemplo prático de um script que simula dias de venda de um vendedor e que extrai apenas os dias em que o vendedor bateu a cota do dia. 
A lista representa o mês (inseri apenas 3 dias para exemplo prático) e os dicionários os dias em si, com valores de venda e KPI's. Nesse script usei a solução mais simples com um laço `For`, vejam:

```
vendas = [{"Dia": '1', "Cota": 3200, "Venda": 2500, "PA": 2, "VM": 1452},
          {"Dia": '2', "Cota": 3200, "Venda": 1803, "PA": 2.4, "VM": 1452},
          {"Dia": '3', "Cota": 5000, "Venda": 8500, "PA": 1.82, "VM": 1385}]
# Objetivo é gerar uma lista com os dias em que o vendedor bateu a cota
print('O vendedor bateu cota nos dias...', end=' ')
for c, dia in enumerate(vendas):
  if dia["Venda"] >= dia["Cota"]:
    print(dia["Dia"], end= ', ')
```

Fácil né?

Agora, e se eu quiser usar uma `lambda` com `filter` para extrair exatamente o mesmo resultado? Intuitivamente, este foi o código que escrevi e não está compilando:

```
# Com filter imprimindo a lista inteira de uma vez
print('O vendedor bateu cota nos dias...', end=' ')
print(list(filter(lambda x['Dia']: x['Venda'] >= x['Cota'], vendas)))
```

Podem me ajudar a construir essa solução com esta funcionalidade? É possível?
Seria legal construir a solução com List Comprehension tb pois não consegui.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

`filter` é uma função utilizada para retornar os itens da sua lista que atendem a condição, e mais nada. Se o seu objetivo é criar uma lista contendo apenas os dias desses itens que atendem a condição, apenas a função `filter` não vai bastar, você também vai precisar de algo como `map`, que serve para transformar a sua lista.

Agora o porque do seu código estar acusando erro, é porque a sintaxe está incorreta. `lambda` declara uma função anônima, da seguinte maneira `lambda [argumentos]: [retorno]`, note que onde você deveria estar declarando os seus argumentos você está declarando `x['Dia']`, isso seria o equivalente a:

```
def minha_lambda(x['Dia']):
    return x['Venda'] >= x['Cota']
```

Essa função é válida? Obviamente que não, o certo seria:

```
def minha_lambda(x):
    return x['Venda'] >= x['Cota']
```

Portanto, a sua função declarada com `lambda` deveria ser `lambda x: x['Venda'] >= x['Cota']`

Em conjunto com `map`, você teria:

```
vendas_filtradas = filter(lambda x: x['Venda'] >= x['Cota'], vendas)
dias = map(lambda x: x['Dia'], vendas_filtradas)
print(list(dias))
```

---

Com `list comprehension` essa abordagem fica mais direta, pois você pode filtrar e transformar sua lista num único passo.

```
dias = [x['Dia']     for x in vendas     if x['Venda'] >= x['Cota']]
#       ^ retorno    ^ laço de repetição ^ condição do filtro
print(dias)
```

Acredito que isso era o que você estava tentando fazer no seu `filter`.

Comment: Perfeito! Uma outra dúvida: por quê temos que sinalizar com list() antes de imprimir o resultado? O Map não gera um objeto list automaticamente?

Comment: @dev.curi, não, a função `map` retorna uma instancia de `map`. Você pode iterar sobre instancias de `map` com um laço `for`, mas `map` não é uma `list`; não tem como adicionar mais itens num `map`, e se você printa-lo diretamente no console vai aparecer apenas `map object at [endereço de memória]`

Comment: bacana @user140828. Então pra visualizar a instância eu devo atribuir um objeto que seja printável (falando a grosso modo), é isso? No caso deste exemplo eu poderia por exemplo jogar dentro de uma tuple, pois eu não vou adicionar nem alterar essa instância. PS. Eu só posso iterar sob a instância desse map() se eu classifica-lo, né?